# Google assistant intergration to app without server connection

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api, app-actions

I am currently creating a remote control app which uses IP control to control devices. I have created this and now I am looking to add a way for you to say for example, "OK Google, Power on 'device' in 'app name'". I have looked at Google's app actions console and I could not find a way to make this as a custom command. I have seen that there is a way to do this by adding deep links into my application. However everywhere I look this requires me to have a host web server which I do not want. Is there any way to do this without a web host or otherwise using the device as it's own host or it's own fulfillment server within the app?

Answer (score 0):

The URL may or may not be resolvable by an HTTP client and it won't send a request to this links. Alternatively, you can also define a custom URL scheme. e.g. `myapp://example/{foo}`.

https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/action-schema#fulfillment